# python click subcommand unified error handling

Tags: python, python-click

In the case where there are command groups and every sub-command may raise exceptions, how can I handle them all together in one place?

Given the example below:

```
import click


@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
def foo():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Both `cli` and `foo` may raise. I know that one possible solution is to place `try-except` around `cli()` in the `if` clause. But that does not work when you distribute a package. In *setup.py*, you have to specify an entry point (in this case, `cli`). The `if` clause will not be executed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a custom `click.Group` by inheriting from same.  The custom group can be used by passing it as the `cls` parameter to the `click.group()` decorator.  If you override the `__call__` method, you can insert an exception handler like:

#### Code:

```
class CatchAllExceptions(click.Group):

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as exc:
            click.echo('We found %s' % exc)
```

#### Test Code:

```
import click

@click.group(cls=CatchAllExceptions)
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
def foo():
    raise Exception('an exception!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli('foo'.split())
```

#### Results:

```
We found an exception!
```

Comment: This doesn't work when attempting to capture the exception in a unit test with the CliRunner. Invoking the custom group as follows:
```
runner = CliRunner()
 result = runner.invoke(cli, 'foo')
 print(result)`
```
prints: "an exception!"